# How to Display Controls when using OnPaint Method in C#

Tags: c#, onpaint, common-controls

How to Display Controls(e.g. `RadioButton`, `Button` etc.) when using `OnPaint` Method in C#? It is possible to create custom controls in constructor, but I need to use common controls of C#? Please suggest.

I'm trying to display common controls but no use. 
Please find below code.

```
private void PaintPanelOrButton(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Point pt1 = new Point(radioButton1.Left + (radioButton1.Width / 2), radioButton1.Top + (radioButton1.Height / 2));
        Point pt2 = new Point(radioButton2.Left + (radioButton2.Width / 2), radioButton2.Top + (radioButton2.Height / 2));

        if (sender is Button)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            pt1.X -= btn.Left;
            pt1.Y -= btn.Top;
            pt2.X -= btn.Left;
            pt2.Y -= btn.Top;
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 4.0F), pt1, pt2);
    }

    public GlassForm()
    {
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.Left = 1000;
        t.Top = 900;
        t.Name = "txt1";
        this.Controls.Add(t);

        this.SuspendLayout();
        Button buttonOK = new Button();
        buttonOK.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        buttonOK.Size = new Size(75, 25);
        buttonOK.Text = "OK";

        Button buttonCancel = new Button();
        buttonCancel.Location = new Point(90, 10);
        buttonCancel.Size = new Size(75, 25);
        buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";

        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { buttonOK, buttonCancel });
        this.ResumeLayout();
        this.TransparencyKey = transparentColor;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            base.OnPaint(e);


            Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
            Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(40, 40, 50, 50);
            Region r = new Region(r1);
            r.Union(r2);

            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath(new Point[] {new Point(45, 45),
                                                    new Point(145, 55),
                                                    new Point(200, 150),
                                                    new Point(75, 150),
                                                    new Point(45, 45)
                                                   }, new byte[] {  (byte)PathPointType.Start,
                                                                    (byte)PathPointType.Bezier,
                                                                    (byte)PathPointType.Bezier,
                                                                    (byte)PathPointType.Bezier,
                                                                    (byte)PathPointType.Line
                                                                 });
            r.Union(path);

            using (Brush transparentBrush = new SolidBrush(transparentColor))
            {
                try
                {
                    BlurBehindWindowEnabled = true;
                    ExtendFrameEnabled = false;
                    if (ExtendFrameEnabled)
                    {
                        var glassMargins = this.GlassMargins;

                        NativeMethods.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref glassMargins);

                        marginRegion = new Region(new Rectangle(10, 10, 600, 100));

                        e.Graphics.FillRegion(transparentBrush, marginRegion);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var glassMargins = new NativeMethods.MARGINS(-1);
                        NativeMethods.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle,
                           ref glassMargins);
                    }

                    if (BlurBehindWindowEnabled)
                    {
                        ResetDwmBlurBehind(true, e.Graphics);
                        e.Graphics.FillRegion(transparentBrush, r);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ResetDwmBlurBehind(false, null);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lbAeroGlassStyleSupported.Text = "Error";
                    demoForm.Show();
                }
            }
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            clsTaskbar.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you want. If you only want to draw stuff that look like a regular control in the system you are running on looks you can use the numerous  `Renderer` classes, e.g. `CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(..)` or use `ControlPaint`..

Comment: I assume the name `GlassForm` is a hint. The problem is that black text is being rendered as transparent, and therefore the controls look wrong? If so, you should describe that in the question, not ask an unrelated question (the one everyone is answering).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want something that look exactly like "normal" controls, but are actually just images.

If so, you can use [`ControlPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint(v=vs.110).aspx) class: it has many methods to draw buttons, checkBoxex, radiobuttons, etc.

Most of them require a Graphics parameter, so you can easily call them from within your OnPaint event handler

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw the controls by yourself, you can search for a xxxRenderer class within the .net framework. By using these you can draw [check boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkboxrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx), [radio buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobuttonrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx), [normal buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx), etc.

But be aware that at is some quite of work, to reproduce the same behavior as the built-in controls (clicking, hovering, focus, keyboard shortcuts, etc.).